# Многомерный объект JS

Tags: javascript

Дана строка с опр. последовательностью

```
var text = "student study english\n student study math\nstudent study Music\n" +
"teacher teaches Ecology\nteacher teaches Math\nteacher teaches Physics";
```

Надо превратить строку в объект данных, например:

```
{
    student: {
        study:["english", "math", "Music"]
    },
    teacher: {
        teaches:["Ecology", "Math", "Physics"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Глубина вложенности одна?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var text = 'student study english\nstudent study math\nstudent study Music\n'
  + 'teacher teaches Ecology\nteacher teaches Math\nteacher teaches Physics';

var data = text.split('\n').reduce(function(data, item) {
  var parts = item.trim().split(/ +/);
  if (3 <= parts.length) {
    var target = parts.shift()
      , action = parts.shift();
    if (!data[target]) {
      data[target] = {};
    }
    if (!data[target][action]) {
      data[target][action] = [];
    }
    data[target][action].push(parts.join(' '));
  }
  return data;
}, {});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: +1 спасибо, а через reduce and map??

Comment: @komandorser, замени forEach на reduce

Comment: @komandorser, обновил с использованием `reduce()`.

Comment: спасибо большое..... как бы это теперь разобрать

Comment: в чем смысл _parts.join(' ')_ если у тебя там один элемент остается?

Comment: @Grundy, например для строки `teacher teaches Higher mathematics`.

Comment: с этой строкой ты не пройдешь в условие `3 <= parts.length`, которое тоже весьма странно выглядит :)

Comment: @Grundy, с этой строкой условие будет `3 <= 4`.

Comment: вот что значит цифра не с той стороны :)